# Clustering or other mechanisms for implementing generic spam detection

Tags: machine-learning, spam

In normal case I had tried out naive bayes and linear SVM earlier to classify data related to certain specific type of comments related to some page where I had access to training data manually labelled and classified as spam or ham.

Now I am being told to check if there are any ways to classify comments as spam where we don't have a training data. Something like getting two clusters for data which will be marked as spam or ham given any data.

I need to know certain ways to approach this problem and what would be a good way to implement this.

I am still learning and experimenting . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In general, no: what you describe is not possible from an information theory standpoint.  I expect that we need to define the problem better.  In your paradigm, what differentiates spam from desired messages?  Without this definition (which implies some form of training or input that you haven't mentioned), you cannot reliably discriminate the two classes.

Comment: While surprisingly simply using KMeans and using some similar features from spam base http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/ and some additional like repeated string score, num symbols , having links score and 12-13 more features ,What I get from that after fetching 3 central clusters out of 5 is 2 of them are almost 90 percent completely spam and one is not. Semi Supervised learning is what worked finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could get to was this [research work](http://ceas.cc/2009/papers/ceas2009-paper-30.pdf) which mentions about active learning. So what I came up with is that I first performed Kmeans clustering and got the central clusters (assuming 5 clusters I took 3 clusters descending ordered by length) and took 1000 msgs from each. Then I would assign it to be labelled by the user. The next process would be training using logistic regression on the labelled data and getting the probabilities of unlabelled data and then if I have probability close to 0.5 or in range of 0.4 to 0.6 which means it is uncertain I would assign it to be labelled and then the process would continue.

Comment: This would reduce the work of labelling for training data. It gives me an accuracy of 87% on the data set I have . For 3000 training set and predicting on 80000 records. In short it helps reduce work.

Answer (score 2):

Are the new comments very different from the old comments in terms of vocabulary? Because words is almost everything the classifiers for this task look at.

You always can try using your old training data and apply the classifier to the new domain. You would have to label a few examples from your new domain in order to measure performance (or better, let others do the labeling in order to get more reliable results).

If this doesn't work well, you could try [domain adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation) or look for some datasets more similar to your new domain, using Google or looking at [this](http://www.aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Spam_filtering_datasets) spam/ham corpora.

Finally, there may be some regularity or pattern in your new setting, e.g. downvotes for a comment, which may indicate spam/ham. In such cases, you could compile training data yourself. This would them be called distant supervision (you can search for papers using this keyword).